# copy constructor gives compilation error

Tags: c++, reference, constants, copy-constructor, temporary

```
  void print_me_bad( std::string& s ) {
      std::cout << s << std::endl;
  }

  void print_me_good( const std::string& s ) {
      std::cout << s << std::endl;
  }

  std::string hello( "Hello" );

  print_me_bad( hello );  // Compiles ok
  print_me_bad( std::string( "World" ) );  // Compile error
  print_me_bad( "!" ); // Compile error; 
  print_me_good( hello ); // Compiles ok

  print_me_good( std::string( "World" ) ); // Compiles ok
  print_me_good( "!" ); // Compiles ok
```

In the above program of copy constructors, why am I getting compilation errors in the second case when I am passing "World"?

Comment: Temporary can't be bound to reference to non-const.

Comment: There's no copy-construction anywhere in the code you show. The problem has to do with the difference between lvalues and rvalues ("temporary" objects, basically) and the difference between references to constant and non-constant objects.

Comment: Binding temporary objects to references (`const` is required) - https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you cannot bind temporary objects to non-const references.

In the following cases:

```
print_me_bad( std::string( "World" ) );  // Compile error
print_me_bad( "!" ); // Compile error;
```

You create a temporary std::string object. First explicitly (`std::string( "World" )`) and then through implicit conversion (`"!"` gets converted to std::string). This is not allowed.

You can, however, bind temporaries to const references, which is why the other cases compile just fine:

```
print_me_good( std::string( "World" ) ); // Compiles ok
print_me_good( "!" ); // Compiles ok
```